# how can i call a dsmlServlet for any operation using java code?

Tags: opendj

I need to perform basic ldap operations using the dsml.war file available with openDJ.
I have deployed the war file but dont know how to make a call to the servlet to perform an operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSMLv2 makes use of SOAP.
You can find a quick example here : http://marginnotes2.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/opendj-getting-started-with-dsml/

Otherwise, OpenDJ 2.6 has a REST to LDAP interface that makes it much easier to access and update data.

Regards,

Ludovic

Comment: Is is better to use Rest or DSML for this?? REST is preferred?